# Validar mes de febrero en char c++

Tags: c++

quisiera saber cómo podría validar información ingresada de fecha. Un ejemplo: el usuario ingresó en día el número 30, pero en mes, escribió "Febrero". ¿Cómo hago para que se pueda limitar los días ingresados, dependiendo el mes que el usuario ingresa (Que se pueda validar siendo mes una variable de tipo char y no un entero)? O debo ponerlo obligatoriamente todo en entero.

```
int dia,ano;
    char mes[10];

    cout<<"Ingrese mes: ";
    cin>>mes;
    cout<<"Ingrese día: ";
    cin>>dia;
    if(mes == "febrero" & dia > 29){
        cout<<"Error en el día ingresado. ingrese nuevamente el día: ";
        cin>>dia;
    }
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: Sólo un pequeño comentario, ya que la respuesta a tu duda está perfectamente respondida. Cuando quieres hacer un 'AND' de expresiones en C/C++ has de hacer un doble ampersand. Cuando se pone uno solo se hace un 'AND' a nivel de bits

Answer (score 3):

La comparación `char[]==char[]` se limita a comprobar las direcciones de memoria de ambos punteros en vez del contenido de la memoria.

Para solucionar este problema puedes usar la función `strcmp`, heredada de C:

```
if( strcmp(mes, "febrero") == 0 )
  // ...
```

O puedes reemplazar `char[]` por `std::string`, opción mucho más natural en C++:

```
std::string mes;
std::cin >> mes;
if( mes == "febrero" )
  // ...
```

Aun así tu código tiene otro error, y es que no es lo mismo `&` que `&&`:

- `&` es un operador binario, es decir, realiza una operación *AND* a nivel de bits:

  ```
  11110000 & 11001100 = 11000000
  ```
- `&&` es un operador que evalúa si las dos condiciones que lo rodean son verdaderas, en cuyo caso devuelve `true`, obteniendo `false` en el resto de circunstancias:

  ```
  false    && false    = false
  false    && true     = false
  true     && false    = false
  true     && true     = true
  11110000 && 11001100 = true
  ```

Answer (score 3):

> Quisiera saber cómo podría validar información ingresada de fecha.

Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, por desgracia C++ no dispone (aún) de una librería de fechas, por lo que la manera de hacerlo es manualmente.

#### Algoritmo manual.

El algoritmo más sencillo para esta tarea implica tener una formación<sup>1</sup> con los días de cada mes:

```
int dias_mes[]{31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
```

Y si el año es bisiesto, sumar un día cuando se verifique febrero. Será un [año bisiesto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1o_bisiesto):

> *Año bisiesto es el divisible entre 4, salvo que sea año secular -último de cada siglo, terminado en «00»-, en cuyo caso también ha de ser divisible entre 400*.

Para comprobar la divisibilidad de años, basta con usar el operador de módulo (`%`):

```
bool es_bisiesto(int anyo)
{
    if (anyo % 100) // Hay residuo al dividir entre 100?
        return !(anyo % 4); // Será bisiesto si no hay residuo al dividir entre 4
    else
        return !(anyo % 400); // Será bisiesto si no hay residuo al dividir entre 400
}
```

Por lo tanto, para limitar los días ingresados, dependiendo el mes que el usuario ingresa:

```
bool es_fecha_valida(int dia, int mes, int anyo)
{
    int dias_mes[]{31,28 + es_bisiesto(anyo) ? 1 : 0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    if (mes > 0 && mes <= 12)
        return dia > 0 && dia <= dias_mes[mes];

    return false;
}
```

Lo único que falta es una conversión de texto a número para los meses, que puede ser tan sencilla como buscar el nombre en una formación:

```
int mes(const std::string &nombre)
{
    const std::string meses[]{"enero",   "febrero",   "marzo",
                              "abril",   "mayo",      "junio",
                              "julio",   "agosto",    "septiembre",
                              "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"};

     auto found = std::find(std::begin(meses), std::end(meses), nombre);

     return std::distance(std::begin(meses), found) + 1;
}
```

Ten en cuenta que el algoritmo anterior sólo evalúa meses en minúsculas, devolverá `13` en caso de no encontrar el mes.

#### Librerías de terceros.

Finalmente, si no quieres complicarte la vida: usa [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html):

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::gregorian::date fecha { 2019, 2, 31 };
        std::cout << "Date = " << fecha << '\n';
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Fecha no valida " << e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior lanza una excepción al intentar construir una fecha inexistente (31 de febrero de 2019). Por lo tanto, para comprobar si una fecha es válida sólo debes intentar (`try`) crearla.

#### Librería *Time* (C++20, documento técnico [p1686r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1686r0.pdf)).

La librería de Tiempo que está en desarrollo para ser lanzada con C++20 permite crear fechas mediante literales:

```
auto fecha = 2019y / 28d / June;
```

Si la fecha no existe, lanza una excepción por lo tanto, para comprobar si una fecha es válida sólo debes intentar (`try`) crearla.

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.